# Facebook Login button custom text reverting

Tags: facebook, text, authentication

hopefully you can help me with this issue.

I've grabbed the basic login button code from the FB developers site and I'm writing it out as is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=345451695525893";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>



<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-  rows="1">Test text</div>
```

The only customisation I'm doing is overriding the default "Log in" text with my own text (in this case "test text"). This works fine when I'm logged out of facebook, but interestingly, when I log in to facebook (via the facebook site on another tab), and then come back to visit my page, the custom text flashes, then the button is rendered a second time with the default "Log in" text.

Any ideas, or is this a feature by design from Facebook?

Comment: AFAIK - as you are using a social plugin from Facebook you're limited to the functionality they expose. The JS code styles up and - obviously - rewrites the div element so that the FB Like button appears consistently wherever used (and also takes in to consideration localisation). 

You do have the choice of verb to use for the button - "Like" or "Recommend" - but that's it afaik.

Comment: Graeme...I noticed the same thing happening on my site, which has been displaying custom login text correctly for years.  It seems that Facebook has made some unannounced (or very difficult to find) changes to the fb-login-button element.

Comment: I hope Facebook is at fault here. I've spent hours debugging today until I found this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the recent changes to the fb-login-button component (which as of a week or so ago seems to ALWAYS rewrite custom text to "Log In"), your best bet is to create a custom CSS class for a Facebook button and trigger FB.Login via Javascript.  That's what I did and it's working nicely.

Here's some CSS for a Facebook button that looks exactly like the standard Facebook button and supports custom text easily:

```
a.fb-button {
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fb-button {
    background: #5F78AB;
    background-image: url('http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yf/r/S-DbSHszr4D.png');  /*COPY TO YOUR OWN IMAGE STORE*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -1px -81px;
    border-top: 1px solid #29447E;
    border-right: 1px solid #29447E;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1A356E;
    border-left: 1px solid #29447E;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 1px 0 #8A9CC2;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 1px 0 #8a9cc2;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 1px 0 #8A9CC2;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 23px;
    line-height: 23px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The element on your page would be

```
<a class="fb-button" onClick="fblogin();">Custom Text</a>
```

And then a JS function like so

```
var fblogin = function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                //successful auth
                //do things like create account, redirect etc.
            } else {
                //unsuccessful auth
                //do things like notify user etc.
            }
        },{scope:'email,publish_stream'}); //whatever perms your app needs
};
```

Of course you'll need to include the fb root div on your page and and init the Facebook JS SDK before this

Here's how it looks:

[image: Facebook button with custom text]

The cool thing about the CSS is that you can use it to create other Facebook buttons on your site for things that aren't supported (like Share) with a familiar look and feel. You can even create some additional css to allow for different size buttons.  You'd just need to have different background positions for the background image and different font size, height etc.

Comment: Heh, seems like Facebook has fixed the issue and the FBML connect buttons are now displaying custom text like they used to.  Carry on.

Comment: ....and then two days ago they stopped..... and then today they fixed it again....   I'd strongly recommend going with the above method and staying clear of FB stupidity!

Answer (score 21):

Use following to use your custom text

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false"  data-width="200" data-onlogin="afterLoginCallback()" login_text="Your Text" ></div>
```

Notice, property `login_text` is provided to set the text on login button. If you don't set it, it will overwrite your text with default one which is provided by Facebook.

Comment: Great answer. Should be more rated. People are using weird custom solutions where the solution is simple.

Comment: it seems login_text not being documented anywhere, but it works, nice find!

Comment: A much more simple and efficient answer! Thank you!

Comment: i wish i could give you 1000 points for that,very easy and effective. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just use:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-login_text="Connect with FaceBook"></div>
```

OR

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1" login_text="Connect with FaceBook"></fb:login-button>
```

Easy as 1,2,3 :)

Comment: in first row please change data-login_text to data-login-text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add data-login-text like this.

```
<div class="fb-login-button"
    data-login-text="Sign in with Facebook"
    data-max-rows="1"
    onlogin="window.location.reload()"
    data-size="large"
    data-show-faces="false"
    data-auto-logout-link="false">
</div>
```